# How to find the Google cached AMP version of any web URL?

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I would like to link to the amp versions of external URLs in my app.  Is there a way to link directly to the Google cached amp version of any external URL falling back to canonical URL if cached amp is not available?

I want to do this without actually parsing the head of HTML of every external URL to see if they have an amp version specified. I want to basically create a script that works like cloudflare - automatically offering a link to the amp version of links if it finds an amp version available.